# Disable disassembly

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to disable disassembly when debugging in Netbeans? It's annoying and I don't use it.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252536

Comment: What is the question, you post an enhancement request in Netbean bugtracker so I'm pretty sure you'll have to wait for the enhancement to be developped, no?

Comment: In case someone knows a trick to disable it.